# preprocessing methods of H2O

Tags: h2o, automl

What preprocessing methods are used in the autoML pipeline? It would be nice to have a brief summary of all these steps in the doc. By preprocessing, I mean: one-hot-encoding, normalization, imputation, etc.

Thank you,

Yassine

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only target encoding is done, but more work is being done to add for preprocessing. See the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html#preprocessing) for more info.